# How to use Django's PasswordChangeView with a custom user?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to use the default [`PasswordChangeView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) to change passwords for users in a project. The problem is that by default it works for the current user. Is it possible to use the view with a custom user, i.e. provided in the URL?

```
# this doesn't work by default
url(r'users/(?P<user_id>\d+)/change_password/$',
    PasswordChangeView.as_view()   
    name="password-change")
```

Comment: You want to change a user's password by accessing a url? Not sure that's a good idea. Do motivate your reason for wanting to do this

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I think that is a good idea if the current_user that enter to that url is a super admin for example.

Comment: I want for an admin to be able to change passwords for other users.

Comment: django admin already have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `PasswordChangeView` is designed to change the password of a user that is already logged in. Then you have to create a view that inheritance from PasswordChangeView and override the method `get_form_kwargs` like this:

```
class _PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = User.objects.get(id=1)  # or any, or get id from url
        return kwargs
```

Be sure of add some permissions to this view, for security reasons. By the way the django admin have this option already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I get the URL parameter value in `get_form_kwargs()` ?